# "Undefined id in Document Collection"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to ***fetch and update data*** from ***firestore collection data*** using form with react & material-ui.

After I update useEffect function, no error found it just not working as my expectation.

[attached file firestore location picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuUy6.jpg)

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 // material-ui
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
 import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
 import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
 import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

// firebase
 import { useFirebase } from '../../../components/FirebaseProvider';
 import { useDocument } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

import AppPageLoading from '../../../components/AppPageLoading';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
```

### the function

```
function EditProduk({ match }) {

const { firestore, user } = useFirebase();
const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
const produkTraining = firestore.doc(`userdoc/${user.uid}/training/${match.params.trainingId}`);

const [snapshot, loading] = useDocument(produkTraining);

const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    trainer: '',
    price: 0,
    description: ''
});

const [error, setError] = useState({
    name: '',
    trainer: '',
    price: '',
    description: ''
})

const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (snapshot) {

        setForm(currentForm => ({
            ...currentForm,
            ...snapshot.data()
        }));
    }
}, [snapshot]);

const handleChange = e => {

    setForm({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

    setError({
        ...error,
        [e.target.name]: ''

    })
}

const validate = () => {
    const newError = { ...error };

    if (!form.name) {
        newError.name = 'Training name must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.trainer) {
        newError.trainer = 'trainer name must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.price) {
        newError.price = 'price must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.description) {
        newError.description = 'description must be filled';
    }
    return newError

}


const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const findErrors = validate();

    if (Object.values(findErrors).some(err => err !== '')) {
        setError(findErrors);
    } else {
        setSubmitting(true);
        try {
            await produkTraining.set(form, { merge: true });
            enqueueSnackbar('Data has been saved', { variant: 'success' })
        }
        catch (e) {
            enqueueSnackbar(e.message, { variant: 'error' })
        }
        setSubmitting(false);
    }

}

if (loading) {
    return <AppPageLoading />
}

return <div>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h1">Edit Training: {form.name}</Typography>
    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <form id="produk-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                <TextField
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    label="Training Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    value={form.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    helperText={error.name}
                    error={error.name ? true : false}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                />
```

### firestore rules

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /userdoc/{uid} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;

    match /training/{trainingId}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

please give me some advise

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think this is related with `function EditProduk({ match })`. The braces in the function definition parameters could cause the object parameters are not available, and undefined  is assigned and it seems it was even used as a string for document name in the database. Please let me know if it will help, as this I just guess.